# Oracle-SQL assign same row_number for rows with duplicate values in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `containing` `FileName`, `CustomerName`, `Address`, Relationship and Index. I want to assign a sequence number to each row, but two customers (primary and secondary) within the same file sharing the same Address will need to share a sequence number, as shown below:

```
FILE    CUSTOMER    ADDRESS Relationship    INDEX   SEQUENCE
1          A           XX      Primary        1        1
1          B           XX      Secondary      2        1
1          C           XX      Primary        3        2
1          D           XX      Secondary      4        2
1          E           XX      Primary        5        3
1          F           XX      Secondary      6        3
```

I tried using
 `DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY FILE, ADDRESS ORDER BY INDEX) AS SEQUENCE`
But the output is still not as shown above.

Comment: Your sample data makes no sense - all six customers are within the same file and they share the same address. How do you know that A is paired with B and not with D or F?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the sample data is already pre-processed and sorted. And I did not include all columns in this table. So a primary customer will always be paired with the next secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `lead` window function get next row `INDEX` in a subquery `ORDER BY Relationship`.

Then use `SUM` window function do the calculation.

```
SELECT 
    "FILE",
    CUSTOMER,
    ADDRESS,
    "INDEX",
    "Relationship",
    SUM(CASE WHEN "INDEX" = 'Primary' AND nextVal = 'Secondary' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY "Relationship") SEQUENCE
FROM (
SELECT t1.*,lead("INDEX") OVER (PARTITION BY "FILE", ADDRESS ORDER BY "Relationship") AS nextVal
FROM T t1
) t1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6628be1d9295280b74f930d6c2330b16)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add `relationship` to the partitioning column:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FILE, ADDRESS, RELATIONSHIP ORDER BY INDEX) AS SEQUENCE
```

Note that this uses `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `DENSE_RANK()`.  Ties don't seem to be an issue.